# Can Spiritjaws hold a manifested ghost or an incorporeal creature?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, grapple

Can Spiritjaws be used to grapple a manifested ghost or an incorporeal creature?

On the one hand incorporeal subtype says that incorporeal creatures can't be grappled. On the other hand force effects generally ignore incorporeality. So which one overrides the other?

I tend to think (but I'm still in doubt) that incorporeal creatures can't be grappled no matter what. But even if it is true, what about manifested ghost? Manifestation description says that manifested ghost "remains partially on the Ethereal Plane, where is it not incorporeal". So should Spiritjaws be able to grapple it's ethereal part?

RC based answers are OK, but try to provide core answer also, please. I am generally skeptical about RC.

Comment: Some previous research on this issue: http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-341535.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**After Reading the [Forum Post](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-341535.html) from [GitP](http://www.giantitp.com)**

**I would allow [Spirit Jaws](http://therafimrpg.wikidot.com/spirit-jaws) to grapple the Ghost** due to their connection of the Ethereal Plane and what Force Effects have on the Ethereal Plane. And as a DM, I would make sure that my ghosts have as many ranks in Escape Artist as possible since their Strength will suck, and so will their BAB.

Despite [Incorporeal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype) creatures not being able to be tripped or grappled - Ghosts are not Incorporeal on the Ethereal Plane. They are merely Incorporeal on the Material Plane when they manifest, but are still anchored in the Ethereal. Force Effects *do effect* ethereal creatures, and despite being incorporeal on the Material Plane, they are still Ethereal.

Comment: As *spiritjaws* is a force effect – not an incorporeal creature – I’m not seeing how the quote tells us why this doesn’t work.

Comment: Manifested ghosts are different from incorporeal creatures though. Addressing that would improve the answer.

Comment: @KRyan So a _Ghost Touch Trip Weapon_ can trip a ghost?

Comment: @Ruut -- that's a bloody good mainsite question if you ask me -- brings to mind images of a ghostly Mr. Wilson having to deal with Ghost Touch Banana Peels being scattered all over :P

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I, unfortunately, am not grasping the idea you are conveying to me.

Comment: @Ruut Imagine that a ghost is a submarine. When the ghost is ethereal it is like the submarine is immersed. The ghost manifests - the submarine floats to the surface (but in our magical world it also means that above_the_water part is let's say immune to explosives [i.e. incorporeal]). But the surfacing won't protect the part that is still underwater from the torpedo (spiritjaws grappling aspect) that is hitting the submarine in the waterline under which it is still vulnerable.

Comment: @Ruut Interesting; it might not be as clear an issue as it seems. [This](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68510/can-spiritjaws-hold-a-manifested-ghost-or-an-incorporeal-creature/68526?noredirect=1#comment148554_68510) contains a lot of discussion about the manifested ghost and Spirit Jaws. Reviewing that should explain the idea better than I can. And I'm interested in your expert analysis of the idea, whether for or against.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am swayed to the side of Pete, Ray, Egon, and Winston body-slamming Slimer.

Comment: While I agree that a manifesting ghost is corporeal on the Ethereal ("A manifested ghost remains partially on the Ethereal Plane, where is it not incorporeal" (*MM* 118)), why is a ghost that's *not* manifesting *also* vulnerable? Is there a reason that I'm not seeing that prevents the not-manifested ghost from being *both* ethereal *and* incorporeal?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I got it that way that ghosts are all and always corporeal on the Ethereal Plane. They are incorporeal on the Material Plane because they enter it just partially. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @annoyingimp There are at least twenty ways to rewrite the sentence I quoted so we'd not be having this discussion. It's nice of the developers to encourage communication between fans. `:-)`

Comment: And I think they doing further steps in that direction in 5e :)

Comment: @annoyingimp The *Dragon* #319 Wizards Workshop column "Sage Advice: Tough Questions: Official Answers" says, "Ghosts have Strength scores in spite of having the incorporeal subtype. A ghost on the Ethereal Plane is not incorporeal" (103). So, although that doesn't make the *text* any clearer, it's a pretty good argument for intent.